# Resolve string encoding by angular

Tags: angular, cookies

I'm using ngx-cookie-service a third party cookie service with angular 7.
i'm trying to set a cookie string like **id=111&name=angular** but angular change it to 
**id%3D111%26name%3Dangular.**

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
export class CookieComponent{
   constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {
      this.setCookie();
   }
   setCookies() {
      let cookieStr: string = "id=111&name=angular";
      this.cookieService.set('cookieName', cookieStr);
      //this set cookieName=id%3D111%26name%3Dangular in browser
   }
   getCookies() {
      let cookie = this.userService.cookieService.get('cookieName');
      //this returns cookieName=id=111&name=angular
   }
}
```

but i need to get cookie from back end but c# does not automatically decode it but angular do.

now how to skip this default angular encoding for this cookie string

Comment: Can you show us? How did you set Cookie and how you are getting cookie value and output result? Provide some more details.

Comment: try setting your cookie with `encodeURI("id=111&name=angular")`

Comment: you mean like this this.cookieService.set('cookieName', encodeURI(cookieStr)); this doesn't work

Comment: @Faisal You want to cookieName value "id=111&name=angular" instead of  "id%3D111%26GUID%3Dangular" in browser?

Comment: yes exactly what i want

Comment: What are you using for backend code? Is that Web API c#?

Comment: c# but i can't change there i want to make it readable to c# by angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngx-cookie-service doesn't provide optional to remove encode/decode feature.

As you can see in below screen shot, each request for **cookie name and cookie value** will be convert into encoded string.

**cookie.service.js** (node_modules/ngx-cookie-service/cookie-service)

[image]

There are two ways you can use,

1st,
I am not recommending this way but you can remove **encodeURIComponent** method.

```
      e.g. var cookieString = name + '=' + value + ';';
```

2nd, You can use **WebUtility** to decode in backed side (WebAPI).

```
      e.g. string cookieString = WebUtility.UrlDecode("id%3D111%26name%3Dangular");
```

Comment: but if edit the code like your first option will this work on server?

Comment: Did you tried? If you publish your code on your local IIS, It will work.

Comment: on localhost this will definitely work but if i publish this to azure will the changes in package works? i think no because we never upload these node module files. how to make it work on server too?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have knowledge about Azure hosting. You should raise this question with Azure hosting tag so expert people can reach.

Comment: ngx-cookie now has an option flag for using unencoded characters, add storeUnencoded: true to the options. Here is an example: this._cookieService.put('cookiekey', 'test@test.com', {'expires': expireDate, storeUnencoded: true});

Comment: @swestfall Yes you are correct but it's ngx-cookie. The questioner can use that would be great but as per his question, he used ngx-cookie-service and that is different than ngx-cookie.